# CREATE INDEX in SQL Server 2008 not result in "visible index"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, covering-index

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express. In the DB in question, there is only one schema: dbo.

If I run the following script:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_ClientSocialTypes_Cover
ON ClientSocialTypes(ClientID, SocialTypeClassID, [Source]) INCLUDE (URLID);
```

... it executes ok, but I cannot see the index when I go into DB Diagram and view the indexes for this table. Further, the "Includes" field is always grayed out, even when I specify non-clustered index (hence my use of a script).

Any ideas?

Comment: See the index where??? Did you refresh the DB diagram after creating the index?? Stupid question: are you sure you're creating the index in the same database as you're looking at in the diagram??

Comment: See the index on "Table right-click, Indexes/Keys". Good grief, I don't believe it. I had to reload the diagram and then it showed!! I am used to the IDE keeping things in sync (such as table edits instantly appear updated). Doh. But... I still don't get why I can't use the IDE to create covering indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you trying to see the index? Did you refresh the database diagram after creating the index?

**Update:** ok, it seems that in the diagram editor, you cannot define included columns (always grayed out - even in **full** SSMS, on SQL Server 2008 R2 Dev Edition).

But in the table designer (right-click on `(your table name) > Indexes > New Index` in Object Explorer),

[image]

it's totally visible and usable....

[image]

Comment: Ahhh thanks! Strange that it's grayed out in the Diagram's Index view!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see it when you run this query?:

```
select * 
from sys.indexes
where object_name(object_id) = 'ClientSocialTypes'
```

Comment: I found the problem. I have to close the diagram and re-open it. It doesn't "refresh" on its own.